# Extra "-" at the end of the line

Tags: bash

I have a .txt file which consists of multiple lines. Some of these lines start with numbers. I want to find these lines and merge them into one line and write the output to another .txt file.

```
Hello
I'm fine
1first
2second
ok
```

I want the result to be like this: `1first-2last`

Therefore I use this code:

```
grep '^[0-9]' first.txt | tr '\n' '-' > last.txt
```

In which `\n` in replaced with `-`, but since there are other lines after the lines starting with numbers, when I open my output file, there is a `-` at the end of the generated line. I mean the last `\n` is also replaced with `-` and the result is like this:

`1first-2last-`

How can I avoid this? I don't want - at the of my line.

Comment: Will the result always be that `last.txt` is a single line?

Comment: @chepner yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace last `-` with a newline.

```
grep '^[0-9]' first.txt | tr '\n' '-' | sed 's/-$/\n/'
```

or with nothing:

```
grep '^[0-9]' first.txt | tr '\n' '-' | sed 's/-$//'
```

But if you want to join the lines with `-` as separator you want:

```
grep '^[0-9]' first.txt | paste -sd'-' -
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'v/^[0-9]/d' '1,$-1s/$/-/' '%j' 'wq last.txt' | ed first.txt
```

This will remove all lines that *don't* start with a number, the add a `-` to every line but the last, then join them, then write the result to `last.txt` (not back to `first.txt`, before quitting without saving the changes to `first.txt`.

```
$ cat first.txt
Hello
I'm fine
1first
2second
ok
$ printf '%s\n' 'v/^[0-9]/d' '1,$-1s/$/-/' '%j' 'wq last.txt' | ed first.txt
33
?
$ cat last.txt
1first-2second
$ cat first.txt
Hello
I'm fine
1first
2second
ok
```

---

`ed` just reads commands from standard input, so you can use a here document if you prefer:

```
ed first.txt <<'EOF'
v/^[0-9]/d
1,$-1s/$/-/
%j
wq last.txt
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is short enough that bash's built-in string handling is adequate, this can be as simple as:

```
readarray -t lines <first.txt
IFS=-
printf '%s\n' "$*" >second.txt
```